# Flatten multidimensional array concatenating keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP convert nested array to single array while concatenating keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882894/php-convert-nested-array-to-single-array-while-concatenating-keys)
>   [Get array's key recursively and create underscore seperated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749398/get-arrays-key-recursively-and-create-underscore-seperated-string)

Please, read the whole question before answering.

I have this multidimensional array:

```
$data = array(
    'user' => array(
        'email'   => 'user@example.com',
        'name'    => 'Super User',
        'address' => array(
            'billing' => 'Street 1',
            'delivery' => 'Street 2'
        )
    ),
    'post' => 'Hello, World!'
);
```

I want it flatten, transformed into:

```
$data = array(
    'user.email' => 'user@example.com',
    'user.name'  => 'Super User',
    'user.address.billing'  => 'Street 1',
    'user.address.delivery' => 'Street 2',
    'post'       => 'Hello, World!'
);
```

**Important**:

- The keys are **very** important to me. I want them concatenated, separated by periods.
- It should work with any level of nesting.

Thank you!

Comment: There are several similar questions, but I have not found a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed, there are two duplicates. I didn't know when asking. Anyway, all answers to them (except meagar's one) are far inferior than the ones given here now... they are unnecessarily complicated (using iterators, globals, classes, and the like, when it can be as simple as we can see here).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for all the given answers.

I have transformed it in the following, which is an improved version. It eliminates the need of a root prefix, does not need to use references, it is cleaner to read, and it has a better name:

```
function array_flat($array, $prefix = '')
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $new_key = $prefix . (empty($prefix) ? '' : '.') . $key;

        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $result = array_merge($result, array_flat($value, $new_key));
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$new_key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 76):

Something like this should work:

```
function flatten($array, $prefix = '') {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix . $key . '.');
        }
        else {
            $result[$prefix . $key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/1dBqx)

Comment: thank you! you also have the counterpart? create a multi-array from this flatten array?

Comment: you sir, thank you, shame it is the last answer in the order, almost did not notice it

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'user' => array(
        'email'   => 'user@example.com',
        'name'    => 'Super User',
        'address' => array(
            'billing' => 'Street 1',
            'delivery' => 'Street 2'
        )
    ),
    'post' => 'Hello, World!'
);

function prefixKey($prefix, $array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
            $result = array_merge($result, prefixKey($prefix . $key . '.', $value));
        else
            $result[$prefix . $key] = $value;
    }   
    return $result;
}

var_dump(prefixKey('', $data));

?>
```

Outputs

```
array
  'user.email' => string 'user@example.com' (length=16)
  'user.name' => string 'Super User' (length=10)
  'user.address.billing' => string 'Street 1' (length=8)
  'user.address.delivery' => string 'Street 2' (length=8)
  'post' => string 'Hello, World!' (length=13)
```

Comment: Really cool, and helpful. Thanks! I will suggest an edit (I removed the need of setting a root prefix).

Comment: Hmmm, as I couldn't, I will post as a separated answer.

Comment: +1 - Led me to the right path. I'd accepted it if didn't require a root prefix.

Comment: changed it a bit so it won't do an initial prefix.

Comment: ah nevermind. it's nearly the same as Felix Kling's solution.

Comment: upvote = 10 points, accept = 15 points; I thanked and gave points to everyone; although all you helped, I will accept my own answer (I receive no points) because it is the code I will actually USE

Answer (score 3):

test this out [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

i passed by reference so no need for returns. just hand over the array storage.

```
$store = array();

function flatten($array,&$storage,$parentKey = ''){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $itemKey = (($parentKey)? $parentKey.'.':'').$key;
        if(is_array($value)){
            flatten($value,$storage,$itemKey);
        } else {
            $storage[$itemKey] = $value;
        }
    }   
}

flatten($data,$store);
var_dump($store);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion such as this:

```
function process_data( $data, $parent_key ){

    if ( ! is_array( $data ) ){
        return $data;
    }

    $flattened_array = array();
    foreach( $data as $key => $item ){
        $flattened_key = $parent_key . '.' . $key;
        $flattened_array[ $flattened_key ] = process_data( $item, $flattened_key );
    }

    return $flattened_array;

}
```

Comment: Cool. +1 But I don't want to specify a root key.

Comment: `$flattened_key = ( empty( $parent_key ) ) ? $key : $parent_key . '.' . $key;`