# How to flatten a multidimensional collection (array) to a dot notation version in a macro (Laravel)?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, recursion, multidimensional-array

**Example input as json**

```
{
   "user":{
      "name":"Thomas",
      "age":101
   },
   "shoppingcart":{
      "products":{
         "p1":"someprod",
         "p2":"someprod2"
      },
      "valuta":"eur",
      "coupon":null,
      "something":[
         "bla1",
         "bla2"
      ]
   }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
[
    'user.name' => 'Thomas',
    'user.age' => 101,
    'shoppingcart.products.p1' => 'someprod',
    ...
    'shoppingcart.something.1' => 'bla1'
]
```

I have written this function however it produces the wrong output. Next to that, I would like to rewrite said function to a macro for `Collection` but I cannot wrap my head around it. The problem is also that the current function as is requires a global var to keep track of the result.

```
public function dotFlattenArray($array, $currentKeyArray = []) {

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $explodedKey = preg_split('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $key);
            $currentKeyArray[] = end($explodedKey);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->dotFlattenArray($value, $currentKeyArray);
            } else {
                $resultArray[implode('.', $currentKeyArray)] = $value;
                array_pop($currentKeyArray);
            }
        }
        $this->resultArray += $resultArray;
    }
```

So my problem is twofold:
 1. Sometimes the function does not give the right result
 2. How can I rewrite this recursive function to a macro

```
Collection::macro('dotflatten', function () {
    return ....

});
```

Comment: Did you look at the existing answers on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546181/4848587 and the linked questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do is called transform an multidimensional array to array with dot notation.

You don't need to reinvent the wheel, Laravel have already a helper for it, called [array_dot()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#collection-method).

> The **array_dot** function flattens a multi-dimensional array into a
>   single level array that uses "dot" notation to indicate depth:
>
> $array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
>
> $flattened = array_dot($array);
>
> // ['products.desk.price' => 100]

You only need to transform your json to array with `json_decode()` and then flat it with `array_dot()` to get an array with dot notation.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a `depth` value as for the Collection `flatten()` method? In my use case my multidimensional array as a constant depth, but i need to flatten in to the second to last level

Comment: Also available as the `Arr::dot()` helper.