# How to access multiple index array dynamically?

Tags: php

For example, i have this array:

```php
$arr = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => 100
        ]
    ]
];
```

I want to somehow pass all the indexes in a string dynamically like

```
$str = 'a.b.c'
```

and use this string to access the array with the string, how can i do it?

I tried something like:

```
$arr[explode('.', 'a.b.c')]
```

But of course it didn't work.

Comment: is it always exactly 3?

Comment: no, it's how many it's necessary

Comment: I believe this one is a "better duplicate" of OP's question: [Flatten multidimensional array concatenating keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546181/flatten-multidimensional-array-concatenating-keys)