# Refactor code from foreach to Laravel Collections

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a JSON file like that

```
{
    "20":{
        "0":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "1":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "2":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "3":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "4":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "5":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "6":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "21":{
        "0":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "1":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "2":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "3":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "4":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "5":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        },
        "6":{
            "period":[
                {
                    "open": 350,
                    "close": 600
                },
                {
                    "open": 660,
                    "close": 900
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

and I have an `action` that is is decoding this `JSON` to array, and pass with `foreach`-es step by step, get that data and then store it in Database.

One guy said me that it is possible to refactor all that action, so I will not have absolutely (or approximative) any foreach or if. Also he said that it is called `representative/functional` programming.

So, I found that concept and all that stuff, but also can't figure out how to do it. 
My `imperial` code:

```
$processingFile = file_get_contents(storage_path('hours.txt'));
$decodedFile = json_decode($processingFile, true);

$data = [];
$i = 0;
$batch = 10000;

foreach ($decodedFile as $business => $days) {
    foreach ($days as $dayOfWeek => $periods) {
        if (count($periods)) {
            foreach ($periods['period'] as $key => $value) { 
                $i++;  
                $tmp = [
                    'business_id' => $business,
                    'day_of_week' => $dayOfWeek,
                    'open_periods_mins' => $value['open'],
                    'close_periods_mins' => $value['close'],
                ];
                array_push($data, $tmp);
                if($i === $batch) {
                    BusinessHour::insert($data);
                    $data = [];
                    $i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if( count($data) ) {
    BusinessHour::insert($data); 
}
```

I don't know how to `parse` step by step and cut it all in functions using `Laravel Collections` or whatever... `declarative paradigm`.

Can someone explain / rewrite that code for teaching purpose?
Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't the json be wrapped in an array just above 20 as 20, 21 etc are multiple objects of the array?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any universal ways that are applicable to your case, given the way you manipulate the information into the final array is not universal (for example, neither the string "period" nor the numerical keys in the *period* array is not used anywhere in the final output while the other keys are used, and the final two child elements are combined into one record, etc).

Here is a bit techy way to prepare `$data` in your example, where the way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882894/php-convert-nested-array-to-single-array-while-concatenating-keys/37078663#37078663) to "PHP convert nested array to single array while concatenating keys?" is adopted.
With this, it uses only one `foreach` (I think one-level loop is inevitable given the fiinal conversion is non-universal).  Note it assumes the input JSON has no irregular structures.

```
$string = http_build_query($decodedFile);
$string = urldecode($string);
$string = str_replace(
              array('[',']'),
              array('_','') , 
              $string
          );
parse_str($string, $flat_array);

$data = [];
$tmp = [];
foreach ($flat_array as $ky => $val) {
    $ary = explode('_', $ky);
    $tmp[$ary[4] . '_periods_mins'] = $val;
    if ($ary[4] == 'close') {
        array_push($data, $tmp);
        $tmp = [];
        continue;
    }
    $tmp['business_id'] = $ary[0];
    $tmp['day_of_week'] = $ary[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to achieve this using the [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-collect) helper, which will add an array to a collection instance and allow you to use its methods.

```
$processingFile = file_get_contents(storage_path('hours.txt'));
$data = json_decode($processingFile, true);
$insertData = [];

collect($data)
    ->each(function ($business, $businessKey) use (&$insertData) {
        collect($business)
            ->each(function ($day, $dayKey) use ($businessKey, &$insertData) {
                foreach ($day['period'] as $period) {
                    $insertData[] = [
                        'business_id'        => $businessKey,
                        'days_of_week'       => $dayKey,
                        'open_periods_mins'  => $period['open'],
                        'close_periods_mins' => $period['close'],
                    ];
                }
            });
    });

if (count($insertData)) {
    BusinessHour::insert($insertData);
}
```

Firstly, we get the `$processingFile` and decode it to a `$data` variable. `$insertData` is created as a new empty array which will be used for later.

Then then wrap the `$data` variable in a `collect()` helper. For each `business` we pass through the reference `$insertData` variable. This is needed in order to update  the variable outside of the collection closures.

Within each `business`, we have `days` so we collect `$business` (which is actually `days`) and for each `day`, pass through the `$businessKey` and the reference of the `$insertData` variable.

After this, we use a normal `foreach` to update the `$insertData` array with new data.

At the end of the process, you then `insert()` all data into records on the `BusinessHour` model.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel collection is really helpful in this kinds of scenario you can break your codes into parts making it readable at the same time attaining a functional programing looks.

```
    $data = file_get_contents(storage_path('hours.txt'));
    $data = collect(json_decode($data, true));
    $batch = 5;
    $data = $this->initMap($data);
    $data = $this->finMap($data, $data->count(), $batch);
    if ($data->count() > 0){
      BusinessHour::insert($data->toArray());
    };
```

Here's the initial map function, what it do is it just prepare all the necesarry data so it can be processed later.

```
    public function initMap($data){
        return $data->flatmap(function($data, $bId) {
            return collect($data)
            ->map(function($data, $day) use ($bId) {
                return collect([
                    'business_id' => $bId,
                    'day_of_week' => $day,
                    'open_periods_mins' => $data['period'][0]['open'],
                    'close_periods_mins' => $data['period'][0]['close']
                ]);
            });
        });
    }
```

And here is the finalization of the data. This compute if the data needs to be save base on the $batch variable, if not remaining data will still be store at the end.

**PS:** Code are base on the OP initial code and I use laravel 8.

```
  public function finMap($data, $total, $batch){
        $this->insertData = [];
        return $data->map(function($data, $index) use ($total, $batch) {
            if (($total - $index) > ($total % $batch)){
                $this->insertData[] = collect($data);
                if (($index % $batch) == 0){
                    BusinessHour::insert($this->insertData);
                }
            }else{
                return $data;
            }
        })->filter(function($data){
            return $data;
        });
    }
```